# Drag and Drop an svg element works with Angular 7 but not with Angular 11

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a project that needs to implement a drag and drop for SVG elements,
So I tried to use the @angular/cdk library with Angular Material but I have a problem.
When I implement drag and drop with Angular version 11, the SVG element disappears when I drag it.
But when I choose to use Angular 7, it works like a charm.

I don't understand why, is it a bug of Angular version 11 or I did it wrong?

I made 2 Stackblitz examples to illustrate my question, you can find them here :

Angular 7: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmvtan-vcspfw?file=package.json

Angular 11: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmvtan-co9kyn?file=package.json

Thank you,
Pierre.

Comment: Any solution to it?

Comment: I'm surprised been a year since the [issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/22051) was discovered, yet still no solution

Comment: Also encountered this. The problem is cdkDragBoundary. Without zone restriction everything works correctly.